# the tooltip in bootstrap doesn't work after ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

I have a file named index.php, which in I include another file named file1.php (in index.php I include all necessary files for jQuery, js etc.).
In file1.php I have a table with buttons which each opens a modal. the information in the modal is from an ajax call for file2.php. in file2.php I create a table. In the table I have the cell :

```
<button class='btn btn-default tooltip-default' data-toggle='tooltip' data-trigger='hover' data-placement='top' data-content='content' data-original-title='Twitter Bootstrap Popover'>AAA</button>
```

and, well, the tooltip doesn't work.
but, when I copy this  and get it to file1.php, bellow the table, the tooltip does work.

Can anyone help me fix the tooltip ?
Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to put the tooltip initialization in Ajax callback function:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "some.php"
}).done(function( msg ) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

-OR-

instead of putting the initialization code in every Ajax callback function
you can implement it globally using the ajaxComplete event:

```
/* initializate the tooltips after ajax requests, if not already done */    
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, request, settings ) {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').not( '[data-original-title]' ).tooltip();
});
```

This code will initialize the tooltip for every node which has the data-toggle="tooltip" attribute defined but do not have the attribute "data-original-title" (i.e tooltip not initialized).

Answer (score 26):

Use selector on exist element like body

```
$('body').tooltip({selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]'});
```

Comment: This worked seamlessly, replacing the use of: $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() after a number of ajax calls.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Thanks. For some reason this worked & Tom's method did not =/

Answer (score 21):

I think you need to initialize the tooltip on the newly arrived data, e.g.

```
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Place this code to your AJAX success handler, after the DOM manipulation.

Comment: The answer worked but to further clarify, I placed the following code at the end of my AJAX page being returned.
<script>
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });
</script>

Comment: I added the code to my AJAX success handler, after the DOM manipulation. It worked, and then it didn't. I'm confused as to why it doesn't always work. I have a form where the user can  select several filters, submit form, and get results...and repeat process. The AJAX runs a query for the results and displays them. It is in the results where I want one piece of data to act as a tooltip or popover. It may work for 1 or 2 form submissions, and then after that it doesn't work. I have to reload the main page to make it work again.

Comment: @Roberto, it maybe because your success function wasn't called, and your ajax is calling the error handler. Calling it inside the complete handler should be more consistent.

Comment: Works for me. tks.

Comment: I have tooltips on a jquery datatable and this worked for me when placed after the table reinitialization in the success handler.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in one of these two ways:

1. you can write an `ajaxComplete` function so that every time after an ajax call completed it reinitialize the tooltip over and over again. This is useful when in most of your pages you have datatables and want to initialize the tooltip after every ajax datatable call:

```js
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("[data-toggle=tooltip]").tooltip();
});
```

2. Or you can call tooltip function after ajax success callback:

```js
function tool_tip() {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
}

tool_tip();  // Call in document ready for elements already present

$.ajax({
    success : function(data) {
        tool_tip();  // Call function again for AJAX loaded content
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried everything and nothing worked for me.
So I took a closer look at tooltip when click* and found out that each time the shown.bs.tooltip is fired a aria-describedby property appears and its value changes every time.

So, my approach (and it works) is to change the content of this dynamic element.

I got this code:

```
$('body').on('shown.bs.tooltip', function(e) {

    var $element = $(e.target);
    var url = $element.data('url');

    if (undefined === url || url.length === 0) {
        return true;
    }

    var $describedByContent = $('#' + $element.attr('aria-describedby')).find('.tooltip-inner');

    if ($element.attr('title').length > 1) {
        $describedByContent.html($element.attr('title'));
        return true;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $element.attr('title', 'Cargando... espere por favor.');
            $describedByContent.html($element.attr('title'));
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        $element.attr('title', JSON.stringify(data));
        $describedByContent.html($element.attr('title'));
    });

    return true;
});
```

In my case my tooltip has a data-url attribute to take the data for the title.
The original title is '-', and I don't want an ajax call every time I click* the element, just the first time.

To me it's not useful to make an ajax every time because I don't expect the data to change that fast.

The dynamic created element has an element with the class .tooltip-inner, so we just need to replace its content.

Hope this might help.

***click**: I chose the click event because the default hover sometimes make the system turn crazy and the show.bs.tooltip was fired forever, switching its between the default and new value.

Answer (score 1):

run

```
$('#ding_me_tooltip').tooltip('dispose');
$('#ding_me_tooltip').tooltip();
```

after the ajax where `#ding_me_tooltip` is your selector

Comment: Thanks @Toskan - this worked for me, the other answers did not

Answer (score 0):

I set up my tool tip by placement like so:

```
function setUpToolTipHelpers() {
    $(".tip-top").tooltip({
        placement: 'top'
    });
    $(".tip-right").tooltip({
        placement: 'right'
    });
    $(".tip-bottom").tooltip({
        placement: 'bottom'
    });
    $(".tip-left").tooltip({
        placement: 'left'
    });
}
```

initialize this with a document ready call:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setUpToolTipHelpers();
    });
```

This way I can determine the placement of the tool tip, and I only have to assign the tip with using a class and title:

```
<td class = "tip-top", title = "Some description">name</td>
```

Then I call, "setUpToolTipHelpers()" inside my success ajax function. Or you can call it on the complete function as well. This seems to work well for me.